# How can I remove x-webdoc from emails using Drupal table of contents links?

Tags: drupal-7, tableofcontents

I am creating newsletters using the Drupal simplenews module. I am using the tableofcontents module. However, on some clients (mostly Mac) the links don't work because they use x-webdoc.

Can anyone suggest how I can get standard links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is an Apple bug. Apparently Apple Mail on El Capitan and also on iOS9 does not like [named anchors](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_a_name.asp).

> The name attribute specifies the name of an anchor:
>   `<a name="C4">Chapter 4</a>`

I discovered this when I had the same problem with a MailChimp newsletter on both platforms but another mail app (Fastmail) on my iPhone had no problems. But AirMail on OS X seems to have the same problem. Strange.

Comment: Hi @PatriciaW, what do you mean with "named anchors"? I'm having the same issue... thanks